# Web References (ASMX) on WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, asmx, .net-4.5

I'm working on a Windows Store App for Windows 8.1, trying to connect to a Web Service.
This Web Service has client implementations for both Web References and Service References. But I'm having trouble to connect using a Service Reference.

I've been using successfully this same web service, by connecting through a Web Reference, but, surprisingly, there's no way to add a Web Reference when using .NET Framework 4.5.1. (There's no compatibility option with the Add Web Reference button like it used to be, inside the Service Reference Advanced Options dialog box).

Since I'm developing for Windows 8.1, i can't target any older version of the .NET Framework.
So, is there any way to work with Web References on Windows Store Apps for Windows 8.1? Is it a bug or they just stopped supporting old platforms? Or maybe i'm missing something.
I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows, using C#.

Comment: `Or maybe i'm missing something...` - you seem to be confusing the WinRT platform with the .Net Framework.

Comment: Maybe i am. I've connected to this web service before, but in a Web Application targeting .NET 4.5.
Now i'm developing a Windows Store App, and i can't seem to find a way to add a Web Reference.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work when you use a service reference?

Comment: I explained it below in response to raja's answer.
There must be a bad implementation of the Web Service when using Service References. But, since Web References are not supported on WinRT (according to Erik Funkenbusch), i'll just have to contact the Web Service developers for a brand new WCF implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web References (.asmx's) are not supported in Windows Store apps.  Sorry, they just aren't.  It has nothing to do with .NET 4.5.1, it's a limitation of the WinRT framework.  You have to use service references with WCF.  If you don't have it, you'll have to write a wrapper service that wraps your asmx to a WCF.

Even Service references are not 100% supported.  This post talks about this more:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/10/19/wcf-for-metro-apps-supported-functionality.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the ASMX URL into the Service Reference dialog box and click OK.
It should be able to create the proxy regardless of svc or asmx services.

Comment: It does, i can indeed create a Service Reference, but i'm having trouble to connect using those classes (maybe a bad WCF implementation from server side), so i just want to add a Web Reference like i used to on my other projects (Web Apps on .NET 4.5), but it doesn't seem like possible.

Comment: if the service url is asmx based, then there is no server side wcf in the picture. what is the error/code snippet etc?

Comment: It's kind of complicated but i'll try to explain myself a little bit more. Using the same url i can add both Web or Service References, so the server supports both implementations. Thing is, the client classes that i get are slightly different.
Using the Web Reference client, i can change the destination url just by passing it as a parameter. That i can't do when using a Service Reference client (changing the endpoint address doesn't work).

Comment: Why i need to do this? For testing purposes, there are different url's that point to different servers with different data on each one.
So, i just want to use the same client classes that i know they work, but that only happens if i add a Web Reference, and i don't seem to find that option anywhere.